# What is the context in which this has been given?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context

" There are several ________ accounts of ________ what __________ when senior advocate Shyam Divan
made a request late in March for an early hearing of a batch of petitions that question the
validity of the unique identification scheme."

What I really do not understand here is how to understand the context in such a long question
when there are so many blanks given.

Comment: You're right, there's no way to fill in these blanks. The first at least seems to be an adjective, but you could use opposite ones (e.g. "differing accounts" or "corroborating accounts"); without the preceding context we don't know anything about the "accounts." I can't even make sense of the next two blanks.

Comment: Yes. I get: There are several *conflicting* accounts of *exactly* what *transpired* when senior ...

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't constitute helping you cheat on homework, but Googling the rest of the sentence reveals the original news story.

Comment: @YosefBaskin We're on the same page!

Comment: @DjinTonic Precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities. For example:

> There are several *differing* accounts of *exactly* what *transpired*
> when senior advocate Shyam Divan made a request late in March for an
> early hearing of a batch of petitions that question the validity of
> the unique identification scheme.

[Answered before the OP added (and removed) the choices]

---

The OP requested some explaining:

It's a question of reading and first trying to mentally "hear" what part of speech or function is required so a phrase or the whole sentence will parse. Context helps determine the basic meaning. If you reread after determining the function of the blank, one or more possibilities should come to mind. It's part syntax and part context/meaning; they work together. It's like looking at the space in a jigsaw puzzle to see the contours of the piece you need to find.

1. *Accounts* (reports) can be *conflicting, differing,  confusing, funny, rambling, published, recent* etc..
2. A verb needs to come **after** "what". We know about the early request from its description, and the verb has to be appropriate to come before "when". We can say that the description, in the most general terms, is describing an *event*. Any verb like *happened / occurred / transpired / took place / ensued* etc. will work.
3. "account of what [transpired/happened]" parses without any intervening word, so we need one that can come **before** "what" to *qualify* it *without changing the basic meaning*. *Exactly, precisely* and *just* work. There are probably just a few choices for this blank, and I came up with these three only *after* realizing what verb is needed **after** "what".

If you have trouble with a blank, try to complete others and then come back to it. It might be a bit easier: *each completed blank adds more meaning to the sentence.* Native and fluent speakers have the benefit of knowing likely collocations—the more common choices and arrangements of words that are used together.

Comment: You're effing brilliant.

Comment: You are right but how did you get the context? Please explain be slightly. Also how did you do it without the options?

Comment: I've added some reasoning that may help.